# styled component pass ref to keen slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a basic version of [keen-slider](https://keen-slider.io/) in react:

```
import { FunctionComponent, ReactNode } from "react";
import { useKeenSlider } from "keen-slider/react";
import "keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css";

interface KeenSliderTestProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const KeenSliderTest: FunctionComponent<KeenSliderTestProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [sliderRef] = useKeenSlider<HTMLDivElement>({
    loop: true,
    initial: 0,
  });

  return (
    <div ref={sliderRef} className="keen-slider">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default KeenSliderTest;
```

Everything is working ({children} are the inner slide... just simple divs with className to work with keenslider).
But if I use style components to style the entire slider, everything is broken:

!! NOT WORKING !!

```
import { FunctionComponent, ReactNode } from "react";
import { useKeenSlider } from "keen-slider/react";
import "keen-slider/keen-slider.min.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface KeenSliderTestProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const KeenSliderTest: FunctionComponent<KeenSliderTestProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [sliderRef] = useKeenSlider<HTMLDivElement>({
    loop: true,
    initial: 0,
  });

  const StyledSlider = styled.div`
  border-radius: 8px;
`;

  return (
    <StyledSlider ref={sliderRef} className="keen-slider">
      {children}
    </StyledSlider>
  );
};

export default KeenSliderTest;
```

I think the problem is the way StyledComponent handle refs, but I really don't know how to pass the correct ref (tried forwardRef... maybe in the wrong way).

Can someone show me the way?